# Download multiple files using jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a webpage, in which we listed set of ebooks. Each ebook item is a link to the actual server location. We provide the user to download the free ebooks, by clicking the book link.

In order to increase the user experience, we are planning to add checkbox against each ebook link, so that visitor can select the book. Finally they can have an option to 'Download Selected'.

Assume user selected 15 ebooks, we wan't the save window to come up one time. ( not 15 windows). If the user select save button, all the 15 ebooks should be saved one after another. Also each ebook is of different size, so we can't predict the time interval b/w subsequent downloads.

Please guide how we can achieve this in jquery/java script.

I am using Sprint & JSP

Comment: I think what would be nicer is if they selected multiple books your server replied with one zipped file with all the books in it

Comment: Yeah, we initially think about it. But currently we are interested not archiving the ebooks in to a zip.

Comment: If only one save dialog pops up, how are you going to name all 15 ebooks to save without placing them in an archive? (hint: you can't)

Comment: Each ebook in the server is having a unique name. So the save dialog only direct me, where to save the books. Once I got the location, I can save all 15 in to the same file system directory. Since the name is unique in server, it won't conflict with each other.

Comment: Right, but the save dialog is a browser thing, you can't control it with javascript.

Comment: Ok.. I got that.. So what will be the best approach ? We are also ready to create a new JSP page for save dialog overlay, with out depending on the browser stuff. Please guide

Comment: You might be able to do something with the https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/File_API/File_System_API, however support for it is very limited.

Comment: +1 for FileSystem API

Comment: Thanks Kevin, but I need a generic solution.

Comment: Stack Experts, pls share a generic solution !